# The proper punctuation of (Thanks + independent sentence)

Tags: punctuation

When a *thank you* phrase is followed by an independent sentence that is related to the thanking part, what is the correct and most proper punctuation to use?

There are many possible ones to apply; thus I have chosen the most three in which I think can state correct punctuation:

> 1- Thank you, it was very helpful!
>
> 2- Thank you! It was very helpful.
>
> 3- Thank you; it was very helpful.

It doesn't, of course, have to be "Thank you", it may also be:

Thanks - Thank you for what you did - Thanks a lot - Thank you very much - ...etc

I have searched about this matter, but the results I got were all about whether to add a comma after "Thanks" in emails or not. [One of the searches](https://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/topic/period-or-comma-after-thanks-and-thank-you)

I also think it may be only a matter of style, so if that is the case, then what would a grammarian use?

*Note:* I would further like to know the formal and informal way of stating the
   punctuation.

Comment: Since ***Thank you*** is a perfectly valid standalone sentence, I'd have thought the most common punctuation mark to follow it would be a *period / full stop* (which you *haven't* included). It's really just a stylistic choice of orthography, but I'd certainly put your semicolon version at the bottom of the pile.

Comment: I agree with the unrealistic excluding of the period punctuation. But what's _wrong_ with the semicolon? Wouldn't it interpret the sentence as: "Thank you since/because/as it was very helpful."?

Comment: Although I still use semicolons myself sometimes, I can't deny that's partly/largely because *I think I know how to use them; I'm "showing off".* Same with the old ***who / whom*** chestnut - if you know exactly what you're doing, *and* you want to appear "erudite", you can throw in the occasional semicolon or ***whom***. But if you don't already know, it's not worth trying to learn things that are falling into disuse; just avoid them.

Comment: (I don't think there's any bulletproof syntactic or semantic argument saying you *can't* use a semicolon after ***Thank you***. All that matters is that competent writers rarely if ever do so. :)

Comment: But readers won't _generally_ find it as an attempt of appearing erudite and/or showing off, will they? Thanks for the detailed explanation by the way.

Comment: Well, "readers" here on ELL (and ELU) aren't exactly "typical". Probably most of the *answerers* (but not necessarily the *querents*) would actually know how to use semicolons (and ***whom***) "correctly". But probably most of them would rarely if ever do so themselves. And if they read my above comment, the *only* reason they might not think "Pretentious twat!" would be because they realise I'm deliberately overusing semicolons *(twice!)* to prove a point. (And I'd *still* put your semicolon version at the bottom of the pile! :)

Comment: _"...to prove a point"_, may I ask what is the point that you are trying to prove? I have noticed its two occurrences and found it a bit odd as you were "criticizing" it and saying that its use is rare among natives.

Comment: It took me some time to understand that you used the semicolon twice ironically, which means that you don't agree with those who find it being used as a way of showing off.

Comment: I doubt you'd find many examples of competent contemporary writers using two semicolons within three consecutive sentences. As Oscar Wilde might have said, *To use one semicolon may be considered impressive; to use two looks like careless / ignorant orthographic posturing*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three are possible and are used. A strict analysis might consider "Thank you" to function as an independent sentence and so should end with sentence punctuation, a full-stop or exclamation mark. A comma is very often seen, especially in the conversational style in which one uses "thank you".  The exclamation mark should be reserved for situations in which you are expressing more than normal joy about the thanks

In very formal writing (the only sort in which someone would care about comma instead of a full stop) a full sentence should be used.

> Thank you. The book token was a nice present.
>
> Thank you! I can't believe you threw a surprise party for me.
>
> We would like to thank you for your interest in this position. However, we have decided not to continue with your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Would "Thank you" still be preferred to end with a full stop or exclamation mark even if it was followed by a short independent sentence like "You too"?

Comment: Yes, I think so, but the point that I was making was: If the writing is formal enough to care about the punctuation following "thank you" then it is formal enough to write out a full sentence, like in the final example that I've given